# zlib z_stream with encryption

Tags: c++, qt, zlib

Trying to create a `z_stream` which is password protected. The code is somewhat similar to [zlib-example](https://gist.github.com/arq5x/5315739#file-zlib-example-cpp). Is it possible to use the encryption along with `z_stream` or is mandatory to use `zipOpenNewFileInZip3` for encryption support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up unrelated concepts. `z_stream` is from "core" zlib, which is for gzip compression (.gz files, gzip/deflate streams), while `zipOpenNewFileInZip3` is from the MiniZip library, which uses zlib to work with .zip (AKA PKZip) files.

If all you want is to have your custom encrypted and compressed stream, nobody is mandating you to use the PKZip format - you can just tie together a `z_stream` with whatever encryption library you like most (just remember to *first* compress, *then* encrypt, otherwise compression will be useless). Of course, this will be a custom file format, so only your decrypter/decompressor will be able to make a sense of it.

If instead you need/want to work with zip files, you can straight use MiniZip functions that support the zip files protection, although keep in mind that AFAIK they only support the "traditional" PKWARE encryption, which is very weak by current-day standards.

Comment: ah, i get it. Had a misconception that the core zlib has password protection support.